# SQL Server Replication if the Tables aren't exactly the same

Tags: sql-server, database, database-replication

I have 2 servers for Production data and Development data for an Application I maintain.  Every year I need to make modification to the application based on business needs.  Of course, the original features need to still work the same (unless of course I modified it).  Currently, the process for testing is quite cumbersome.

To solve this issue, I want to set up to replicate the data from Production to Development.  This way I can look at the reports and check 1 to 1 if the new application is working correctly.

I have never used replication before, so I am looking through how to set it up now but there is one potential issue that I cannot find an answer to.  Since business needs change, I have added some new fields and removed some fields to tables in the Development database.  It is 99% the same but it is different.  I am curious if this is still the correct strategy? and if not, what should I move towards?

Also, do I need to delete all the data out of the Dev Server before I replicate it back? Or will the replication get rid of any data that isn't on the server, automatically?

Comment: Replication means exactly that -- the two sides are an exact copy of each other.  That's not what you need.  What you need is a careful script that can convert Production to Development.  Then, you can run that during your development process to pull a snapshot for your testing, and when it's time to go live, you can run it on the production server itself.

Comment: Needing to change your database design every single year to meet some changes in the application is a big red flag that the database design is less than ideal. This whole question sounds like the best solution would be to fix the table design so you don't have to change it all the time.